# I am restructuring my Flask-restful app, but having trouble placing the HTTP-auth in order to get app running

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-httpauth

Essentially, I have a directory as such:

```
/app
  runserver.py
  /myapp
    __init__.py
    api.py
    auth.py
    /resources
      __init.py
      users.py
      login.py
    /models
      __init.py
      models.py
    /common
    /assets
```

In my auth.py I have a standard HTTP-basic username/password authentication. I will use these for areas where login is a must, and I want to verify each user. Login.py is where I need to add my decorator, but the whole app does not run due to this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'login_required'

```
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
    if not user or not user.verify_password(password):
        return False
    g.user = user
    return True

@auth.error_handler
def unauthorized():
    return make_response(jsonify({'message': 'Unauthorized'}), 403)
```

My code for the login.py, which calls the decorator and then asks for the auth.

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from myapp.models.users import User
from myapp import auth 

class login(Resource):
    decorators = [auth.login_required]

    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('userid', type = str , default="")
        self.reqparse.add_argument('username', type = str,  default="")
        self.reqparse.add_argument('password', type = str,  default="")
        super(login, self).__init__()


    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        username = args['username']
        password = args['password']
        message = {'status': 'Authorized'}
    return message
```

So to wrap it up, my question is: How and where do I add the flask-httpauth class so I can use the decorators. My option right now may be to paste that auth code in every resource class that needs it, but there seems there must be a better way to organize that. Help?

Answer (score 2):

You are importing your `auth` module when really you want to be importing the `HTTPBasicAuth` object in that module. It is also possible you're running in to problems due to the fact that your module has the same name as the `HTTPBasicAuth` object.

I recommend renaming your `auth.py` to something else, such as `authentication.py`, and change your import to:

```
from ..authentication import auth
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused what the difference between what I've done and what you are suggesting is? So in my login.py, I do  from myapplication.authentication import auth? Isn't that the same thing as doing from myapplication import auth?

Comment: It is different because you are importing the module when you really want to import the `auth = HTTPBasicAuth()` object

Answer (score 0):

This gets a bit confusing because you have an `auth.py` module that defines an `auth` variable inside.

The line:

```
from myapp import auth
```

is importing the module, not the variable defined in it. Change it to:

```
from myapp.auth import auth
```

And I think that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is a bit old, but for the sake of others with this question, I would suggest not using flask.ext.httpauth. I found it isn't very useful. Here is how I do my HTTP basic auth with flask-restful.

This is in the myapp/**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.ext.restful import abort

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth:
            abort(401)
        user = User.query.filter(User.username == auth.username).first()
        auth_ok = False
        if user != None:
            auth_ok = verify_password(auth.password) == user.password
        if not auth_ok:
            return abort(401)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Resource script that has a resource that requires authorization to access the resource.

```
from myapp import requires_auth

@requires_auth
def get(self):
    # do something
```